# drawing world map with provinces

Tags: google-maps, google-visualization

I want to draw a geochart map of the world together with US states and canadian provinces. By default it is set that United States and Canada are shown on the map as a single country without states borders, like this:
http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/11/World_map_ICC_member_states.png
I want to make the map like that one: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b6/MAP_OF_WORLD_with_states_Booksworm_travels.png

I was trying with changing the resolution to 'provinces'. Unfortunately it didn't work.
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no current way to do this in Google Geocharts as there is no province-resolution map for multiple countries (the SVG doesn't exist). You can either do Canada, or the US, but not both.

Sorry for the bad news.